# Trouble uploading files with special characters

Tags: php, file-upload

I have coded a little upload script that works just fine in every case when I use it, but I always get messages from my client that he gets an error that I die() when the upload goes wrong/doesn't work.

I believe that this was caused by the special characters they use. Because they are Austrians they have special chars like äÄöÖüÜß in their filenames. Plus they use whitespaces in there filenames.
Therefore I used a regex to replace special characters into underlines(_).

```
$moveFile = function($tmpname,$name,$time) {
                    // the regex to resolve the special chars problem
            $name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/s', '_', $name);
            if (!move_uploaded_file($tmpname,'assets/siteContents/bewerbungen/'.$time.'_'.$name)) {
                die('something went wrong while uploading');
            }
        };

        // move application_files__image
        $moveFile($_FILES['application_files__image']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['application_files__image']['name'],
            $time);
        // move application_files__image
        $moveFile($_FILES['application_files__cv']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['application_files__cv']['name'],
            $time);
        // move application_files__certificates
        if (count($_FILES['application_files__certificates']['name'])) {
            foreach ($_FILES['application_files__certificates']['name'] as $i => $name) {
                $moveFile($_FILES['application_files__certificates']['tmp_name'][$i],
                    $_FILES['application_files__certificates']['name'][$i],
                    $time);
                $a_list[] = 'assets/siteContents/bewerbungen/'.$time.'_'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/s', '_',$_FILES['application_files__certificates']['name'][$i]);
            }
        }
```

If the error isn't caused by the special chars in the filename I am not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: I was trying out this http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: What you mean is that `move_uploaded_file()` returns `false`? In that case, the manual says it should throw a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns FALSE on this conditions:

1. > If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
   >   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
2. > If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
   >   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
   >   FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

[(Source: PHP.NET)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

1. You are filtering your filename with this regex `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/s` but this will only replace the first occurence of a special char not all.
   Try adding the "g" modifier: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/sg`
2. Are you sure your client has the right permissions to move the file
   to the desired location? I would double check them.

Comment: The Regex works fine. If I upload a file named "Das ö ist groß.pdf" I it renames it to "Das___ist_gro_.pdf".
It can't be the permissions because this is a webform and the script is processed by the apache/www-data and since I can upload, they should be able to upload to.

But thanks already :)

Comment: Hmm...
Can you check if `$_FILES['yourfile']['error'] == 0`?
If it's 0 the upload went well but there is a problem with moving the file, otherwise it's a problem with the upload.

Comment: If it fails the function gives an error explaining why... 
Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the file.

Comment: I tried this but I didn't get any errors. And I simply can't ask my client to test the script every 10 mins ... sry